# Name of this 2-categorical structure?

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

Let $\mathscr C$ be a 2-category. For each object $X$ in $\mathscr C$ suppose there is a category $\mathcal R(X)$, and for each pair of objects $X,Y$ in $\mathscr C$ there is an "action" functor
$$
\rhd \colon \mathscr C(X,Y) \times \mathcal R(X) \rightarrow \mathcal R(Y)
$$
which satisfies compatibility with the composition and unit of $\mathscr C$, i.e. the diagrams
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathscr C (Y,Z) \times \mathscr C(X, Y) \times \mathcal R(X) @>{\mathscr C(Y,Z) \times \rhd}>> \mathscr C(Y,Z) \times \mathcal R(Y)\\
@V\circ \times \mathcal R(X)VV @VV\rhd V \\
\mathscr C(X, Z) \times \mathcal R(X) @>>\rhd> \mathcal R(Z)
\end{CD}
$$
and
$$
\begin{CD}
\mathcal R(X) @>{u \times \mathcal R(X)}>> \mathscr C(X,X) \times \mathcal R(X)\\
@| @VV\rhd V \\
R(X) @= \mathcal R(X)
\end{CD}
$$
commute.

Does this structure have a name? Or is it an example of something more general? The point is that $\mathcal R(X)$ is a left $\mathscr C(X,X)$-module category for every $X$, but these more general rules are still satisfied.

Comment: This is just a 2 functor $\mathcal R \colon \mathscr C \to \mathbf{Cat}$, right?

Comment: I have trouble working out all the details, but a category is the same thing as a monad in $\mathsf{Span}$, and it looks a lot like a module over $\mathscr{C}$ seen as such a monad, except I don't know what to make of the fact that $\mathscr{R}(X)$ is itself a category. It's like a "left algebra over a ring" (except "ring" is "monad" here).

Comment: well a functor $\rhd \colon \mathscr C (X,Y) \times \mathcal R(X) \to \mathcal R(Y)$ corresponds under the closed monoidal structure of $\mathbf{Cat}$ to functors $\mathscr C(X,Y) \to [\mathcal R(X), \mathcal R(Y)]$, and now this looks like a 2-functor

Comment: Ohh I missed the fact that $\mathscr{C}$ is a 2-category. I'm writing an answer right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\CC}{\mathscr{C}}\DeclareMathOperator{\ob}{ob}\DeclareMathOperator{\mor}{mor}\newcommand{\RR}{\mathscr{R}}$The "2-category" aspect is a bit of a red herring in my opinion. It may be easier to first consider the case where $\CC$ is a category, and $\RR(X)$ is a set for all $X$. But I'll do the case of 2-categories anyway.

Let $\mathsf{Span}(\mathsf{Cat})$ denote the [2-category of spans](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/span) of categories. A 2-category can be seen as a [monad](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad) in $\mathsf{Span}(\mathsf{Cat})$:

- the "category" of objects $\ob \CC$ is the discrete category on the set of objects,
- $\mor\CC$ is the disjoint union of all the categories $\CC(X,Y)$ for $X,Y \in \ob \CC$,
- $\Sigma = (\ob\CC \xleftarrow{s} \mor\CC \xrightarrow{t} \ob\CC)$ is the span "source-target",
- $\eta : 1_{\ob\CC} \to \Sigma$ maps an object to its identity,
- $\mu : \Sigma \circ \Sigma \to \Sigma$ is the composition.

Let $\RR$ be a category and suppose it's equipped with a functor $p : \RR \to \ob\CC$, and let $\RR(X) = p^{-1}(X)$ so that (remember that $\ob\CC$ is discrete):
$$\RR = \bigsqcup_{X \in \ob\CC} \RR(X).$$
Consider the span $x : \RR \to \ob\CC$ in $\mathsf{Span}(\mathsf{Cat})$ given by $\RR \xleftarrow{=} \RR \xrightarrow{p} \ob\CC$. Then your $\rhd$ and the relations it satisfies are exactly the data necessary to make $x$ into a [left module](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/module+over+a+monad) over the monad given by $\CC$.

---

Summary: This is a special case of a left module over a monad in $\mathsf{Span}(\mathsf{Cat})$. If, as I suggested at the beginning, you had a category $\CC$ and a collection of sets $\RR(X)$, this would similarly be a left module over the monad in $\mathsf{Span}(\mathsf{Set})$ given by $\CC$ (without the funky condition on $\ob\CC$ that says it's a discrete category).

PS: In general, a monad in $\mathsf{Span}(\mathsf{Cat})$ is a category internal to $\mathsf{Cat}$ (general fact about monads in spans), a.k.a. a [double category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/double+category). I'm viewing 2-categories as special double categories here – I don't know if this is important.